# Salesforce dataset with many fields

Tags: salesforce, custom-object

I have a dataset with over 90 fields that can be put into about 4 groups. 
I was wondering if I could put this in Salesforce. 
To update 1 record with 90 fields would be cumbersome. What would be great is if there was something like the Wizard Object in ASP.NET where related fields could be grouped together and the user could go from one group to another updating the values as he went along. 
Is there any way of doing this? How does Salesforce manage long records like this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question of data modeling than data loading. Data loading a single object with 90 fields (which is not that many) is trivial. But if the issue is that those 90 fields don't belong together on a single object, then you will need to decide which objects are needed, create them, create the fields, and then split the dataset into individual data load operations.